# Passing variables to the view from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i open a view in AppDelegate

with:

AppDelegate

```
PushDetail *pushdtls = [[PushDetail alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];   
pushdtls.seminarurl = [NSURL URLWithString:resourcePathURL]; /passing URL
[self.window presentModalViewController:pushdtls animated:YES];
```

PushDetail.h

```
@property (nonatomic) NSURL *seminarurl;
```

PushDetail.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:seminarurl];
    [pushDetails loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

But the webview is empty... what I do wrong?

and the second question how to close the view I opened?

```
- (IBAction) closeNews{
    //[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    //[self release];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

You may implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol within your view controller and fetch the results/error messages yourself.

Namely `didFailLoadWithError` - see the [UIWebViewDelegate Protocol References](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for more.

Maybe its just a typo on your URL.

Example:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"oops, failed with error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: there are no errors... if I write this in my push detail view seminarurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.de"]; everything is fine

Comment: Well, then it must be the faulty content of `resourcePathURL`. NSLog that one and check yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You've not specified what pushDetails is, but I'm assuming it's an IBOutlet to a UIWebview on your PushDetail controller. My guess is that you've forgotten to bind your pushDetails outlet to the webview in your nib file.

Comment: sorry,  pushdetail is a controller with a uiwebview

Comment: Yes, that's what I assumed. Did you check if you bound the outlet then?

Answer (score 0):

You could create lets say a file that holds all your global variables lets call it GlobalVariables.h and .m. In the GlobalVariables.h file add this

```
extern NSURL *seminarurl;

@interface GlobalVariables

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSURL *seminarurl;    

@end
```

and in the GlobalVariables.m file add

```
#import "GlobalVariables.h"

@implements GlobalVariables

@synthesize seminarurl;

NSURL *seminarurl; // You could add what your URL is here as well you would just use '='

@end
```

So when you want to access it or assign a variable to it, it would just be like accessing or assigning any other variable. Just remember to import 'GlobalVariables.h' into which ever .m file you are using it in.

Answer (score 0):

1. make your property retained. ex >> `@property (nonatomic,retain)`.
2. if the url is a property in your app delegate .. you can access it like this

   [UIApplication SharedApplication].delegate.yourpropertyname;